# How to mock method in one struct golang

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a piece of code like this where Bar function called inside Foo function.

```
type MyInterface interface {
 Foo() bool
 Bar() bool
}

type MyStruct struct {
 ...
}

func NewFuncForDI() MyInterface {}

func (a *MyStruct) Foo() bool {
//...
fromBar := a.Bar()

return fromBar
}

func (a *MyStruct) Bar() bool {
//...
 return true
}
```

I'm using testify and it's work very well if I called another function from different struct, but how to mock a function called by another function in one struct? Is there any way I can make mock function for Bar?

Comment: I think if two interfaces have a relationship, they should be defined separately. Then you can mock then easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to mock out just the `Bar` function. What you can do is convert the code that you want to mock in the `Bar` function into a variable on the `MyStruct` class and inject a mock value for that. For example, if `Bar` used `time.Now()`, you could modify `MyStruct` to be the following:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    nower func() time.Time
}

func (a *MyStruct) Bar() bool {
    now := a.nower()
}
```

Another alternative, is to replace concrete objects inside your struct with interfaces (`s3iface` vs `s3` for example). Finally, if you're having trouble testing just one function on your struct it's probably a good indication that you need to split that code into a separate struct.